# SQL: How to use SELECT results as function input parameters

Tags: mysql, function, select, input

Here is my query:

```
SELECT
  CASE
      WHEN hbn.users.showDistance = 'T' 
      THEN hbn.distance(u2.lat, u2.lon, hbn.users.lat, hbn,users,lon)
    ELSE 0
  END as distance,
hbn.users.id,
hbn.users.username,
From hbn.users,
(select hbn.users.lat, hbn.users.lon from hbn.users where hbn.users.id = '1') AS u2
where hbn.users.Id = '8';
```

This does not work!
I need to use output of the second select statement as input for distance() function.

Comment: FYI, It looks like you have conflicting where clauses between your main query and your subquery `hbn.users.id='1'` and `hbn.users.id='8'`.  I don't know if that's causing your problem though

Comment: Please explain what doesn't work about this query.  Does it not even run?  Does it just not give you the results you expect?  Also, what results ****DO**** you expect?

Comment: Please post what is the error message you're having.
In your CASE statement if the 'showDistance' is not equal to 'T', then you'll have the column 0. I'm not sure that's possible.
And I also reinforce what jadarnel27 said.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have commas instead of full-stops in the last parameter to hbn.distance?

Comment: Also, is the comma after hbn.users.username valid?